# How to define the Lebesgue measure on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

I am confused by notes we previously made. Let $\mathcal{B}^{d}$ be the Borel sigma-algebra and $\lambda^{d}$ be the Lebesgue-Borel measure. It was defined as follows:

For all $Q:=\times_{i=1}^{d}[a_{i},b_{i}[$ where $-\infty < a_{i} \leq b_{i} < \infty$ $\forall i = 1,..., d$. It follows that:

$\lambda^{d}(Q)= \prod_{i=1}^{d}(b_{i}-a_{i})$

Let's look at the case $d=1$ and we know $\mathbb R \in \mathcal{B}$ by sheer definition of a $\sigma-$algebra. But surely since 
$\lambda(\mathbb R)=\infty$, it cannot be Lebesgue measurable? Or am I confusing definitions here?

Comment: No, a measurable set can have infinite measure. So there is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset $B$ of the set $A$ is measurable or not w.r.t. the sigma algebra $\mathscr A$ on $A$ if and only if $B\in \mathscr A$, we don't need measure.

In case of Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^d$  we first define Lebesgue outer measure $\lambda^*:P(\Bbb R^d)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ as $\lambda^*(A)=$ infimum of of all sums of the form $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} vol(R_j)$ where $R_j$ is a bounded $d$-dimensional rectangle of the form $\times_{i=1}^{d}[a_{i},b_{i}[$ with $-\infty < a_{i} \leq b_{i} < \infty$ such that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} R_j\supseteq A$ . Now we define a subset $B$ of $\Bbb R^d$ is Lebesgue measurable if it satisfies the equation $$\lambda^*(A)=\lambda^*(A\cap B)+\lambda^*(A\cap B^c),\forall A\in P(\Bbb R^d).$$ You can show that collection $\mathcal M$ of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\Bbb R^d$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and our Lebesgue measure is nothing but $\lambda^*|_{\mathcal M}:\mathcal M\rightarrow [0,\infty]$.

Comment: Ok, but how can I "cover" $\mathbb R$ with rectangles of the form $[a_{i}, b_{i}[$ ?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{x\in \Bbb R} (x,x+1)$. Now 2nd countability or Lindelof property (every open cover has a countable subcover)of $\Bbb R$ implies that $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} (x_i,x_1+1)\implies \Bbb R=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} [x_i,x_1+1)$ for some $\{x_i\}\subset \Bbb R$

Comment: Obviously you can also construct cover by closed-open intervals without using Lindelof or etc.